# Samsung "Kies via Wifi" doesn't work, stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: wireless-networking, android, mobile-phone

When I connect my Galaxy S2 to my laptop using "Kies via Wifi" it doesn't work.

On my phone it tells me it is connected, and on the laptop I can see the device "GT-I9100" under connected devices, but I see no files or anything else.

When I move the mouse icon over the "GT-I9100", it writes "Loading...". I've waited long enough but nothing happens.

When I connect the phone using USB cable, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many users have issues with Kies via WiFi.  I believe Samsung intends for Kies Air to replace Kies WiFI.  My new SGS II on Sprint didn't even have Kies WiFi installed.

Kies Air uses a browser based interface and displays your files already categorized by type.  You can upload, download, or view any file.  It relieves you from having to figure out the Android file system and where files are stored.

Start Kies Air on your phone, open your browser, and enter the IP address that Kies Air displays on your phone, which will be something like "http://192.168.1.xx:8080/" .  The Kies Air app on the phone will pop up a message that a device is trying to connect.  Approve the connection and the Kies Air interface will appear in your browser.  Here's a YouTube demo - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6wIQoXqRDI

Comment: Kies Air is for accessing your stuff on the phone.  Kies WiFi is for syncing your stuff with your laptop/desktop.  Those are pretty different things.  If I put a new contact in Outlook, for example, Kies Air will not sync it AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.  Galaxy S2.  Kies Air works fine.  Kies via Wifi gets stuck on Loading...

It used to work on my old (Vista) computer, but not on this new (7) one.  I've also upgraded Android from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 recently, so it may be that that's caused the change, rather than Vista to 7.

Kies Air is very clever, but doesn't allow sync of contacts with Outlook.  I don't want my contacts living in Google's cloud, so I don't have them stored in gmail or Google+.  They just live on my phone and in Outlook.  Everything else (calendar etc) is synced over the air, but I need to use Kies to sync my Outlook contacts offline.  That means Kies via Wifi and not Kies Air, unfortunately.

For the time being, I'm left with no alternative but to plug in and sync to Kies by USB cable.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same issues and finally got the SII to sync via wifi with outlook.

The main issue I have encountered is that "loading" takes 10 minutes.

It is TOO LONG... I am worried that power saving protocols on the phone may break the connection before it has finished "loading".

I have a 32GB SD card, half-full with a few movies. Perhaps I have too much memory.

I have all antivirus-firewall deactivated. Once I can get it to connect via wifi repeatedly, I shall activate these and see if they are a problem.

I have just had it connect again, it took 9 minutes, from 11:17 to 11:26.

In addition I have toyed with WPS on the router and gone over the network and service configuration as stated in the samsung tutorial. Most of them where correct on the 3 PC I have tried.

8 minutes to "load" is too long... On USB cable or with Kies Air it is instantaneous...

At least I have "seen" the smartphone sync to outlook :-)

I feel the purpose in my life has been fullfilled...

Now I can continue to sync via USB :-)

P.S: Kies Air does not sync. I repeat, Kies Air does not sync. Kies Air CONNECTS your device to the PC via the web-browser, allowing you to manage the information in your phone, but without the posibility of syncronising with Outlook and other programs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your answer is much appreciated but there is to much written in the answer which is not relevant to the question itself. I will remove my -1 when the text has been rewritten to just answer the question instead. Cheers.